# callback to be called before any objects with automatic storage duration are destroyed

Tags: c++

Does there exist a standard (any C++ standard) way to register a callback, that gets called shortly before any objects with automatic storage duration are destroyed as part of normal program termination?

EDIT:

To make this more clear. It's a multi-threaded application. Some objects may have pushed functors into a thread pool, that reference them (functor accesses the "originator" object). The thread pool object is static, so it gets destroyed **after** `main()` returns and so after all these objects who pushed functors into the thread pool, that are referencing them, have already been destroyed. The thread pool is flushed upon termination and so the functors have dangling references to "originator" objects in them.

Comment: what about destructors?

Comment: Yes, but each class has it's own, all would have to have a hook mechanism installed. Not to mention objects of non-class type.

Comment: you want a single callback before program termination or one callback each time an object gets destroyed?

Comment: one callback, just before main() returns, but without me having to fiddle with main(). Such as, putting SCOPE_EXIT(&, exit_callback()); into main().

Comment: add a function to the bottom of main?

Comment: sure, that's a possibility, but I was hoping for something else, fancier.

Comment: and for your specific problem, I"d recommend using shared pointers for the work, so there are no danglers.

Comment: @xaxxon This would exclude objects allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

std::atexit should do what you want:

> Registers the function pointed to by func to be called on normal program termination (via std::exit() or returning from the cpp/language/main function)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit'

you may want to put something on std::terminate_handler as well.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler

Comment: No no, by that time, some objects are destroyed already. Those allocated in main().

Comment: main is not special -- all automatic variables in a function are cleaned up when a function ends.  If you want something run when an arbitrary function ends, you can trivially make your own.  Cleaning up variables in main is not a part of program termination.  The only thing that is "hard" is dealing with things like static variables - and this is the solution for those.

Comment: @user1095108, if you call `exit()` explicitly, automatic variables will not be destroyed.